# How to replace Perl's deprecated find.pl

Tags: perl, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I am attempting to update legacy Perl code that is using find.pl via "require". The find.pl module is no longer available in newer versions of Perl.

I have this notion that I can replace a "require" of find.pl with a "use" of File::Find, but I am not sure how to make the transition.

Also, I am not sure what functions other than "find()" might be affected.

I did web and SO searches for find.pl and all I got was acknowledgement of the deprecation/removal of the module and various side effects of that.  I did not find help for converting code that uses find.pl.

I appreciate any tips and suggestions for making this transition.

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot try and see what happens? Change the module as you say, and replace calls that you can tell need replacing. Then if problems come up you can show that in the question -- along with the code that need be adapted.

Comment: @zdim, I could possibly do that.  I am wishing that I had a simple easy verification test to validate the results.

Comment: Well, sure, I've no idea how to validate your code and its uses, of course.  But then I cannot have much of an idea of how to do what you ask either, without seeing the code.  There is no blanket "solution" to replacing modules (except for those which are drop-in replacements).

Comment: Right.  I am not asking for help with the test.  Just for suggestions for replacing find.pl.  Since this module has disappeared, it seemed to me that someone else likely has had to make a change from find.pl to something else.  I am hoping to tap into that experience of others if it exists here.

Comment: Got that; i still recommend that you just do it. I looked and found a couple of links, [like this one](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/29989/), which seem to show how that `find.pl` relates to `File::Find`.  However, I have no idea whether this is really "your" `find.pl` and whether it will work.  Since you obviously have the file on your system, look it over and see what subs it offers then go through your code to find which of those it uses.  Then replace them.  Or wait for someone to possibly come along and says, 'oh this is what you need...'

Comment: @zdim, thanks for that example.  Looks like a fairly simple replacement of `find(x)` with `File::Find::find(\&wanted, x)`.

Comment: Well, great if that helps ... but I'd be weary of bluntly applying a recipe like that to my code.  Use it, sure (if that's that), but please also review in detail _your_ actual code, both that `find.pl` on your system and the code that uses it.

Comment: From what I can tell, that link provides a fix for a situation where an old `find.pl` disappeared while some tools need it; so they restored its operation using `File::Find`, supposedly knowing how their `find.pl` worked. But will that work for _your_ situation?  What is the `find.pl` that they are dealing with?  I'm afraid that it'd be best that you go through all relevant code and check, and perhaps write a separate test for your replacement code against your `find.pl` operation.  So to ensure you don't end up with _nasty_ bugs. A price to pay for deferred maintenance.

Comment: Re "*The find.pl module is no longer available in newer versions of Perl.*", Not true. You can find it as part of the [Perl4-CoreLibs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl4::CoreLibs) distribution. That said, it would be wise to move away from it in favour of [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find::Rule).